# MySQL using routine output to join on table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, routines

I have a routine that is called using

```
SET @p0='55'; SET @p1='-6'; SET @p2='100'; CALL `distanceSearch`(@p0, @p1, @p2);
```

Basically i pass in latitude, longitude and a distance to search for users, e.g 100 miles. The routine creates a temp table and inserts results into it. When i execute it, a result set is returned.

When i try execute it like this i run into a syntax error

```
SET @p0='55'; SET @p1='-6'; SET @p2='100'; 
select foo.* from (CALL `distanceSearch`(@p0, @p1, @p2)) as foo
```

What am i doing wrong? How do use the results from this to join on another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, you can't perform a select from procedure like that way but as you said *The routine creates a temp table and inserts results into it*

in that case if you already know the temporary table name then do a `SELECT` from that table

```
select * from temporary_table_name
```

Else, convert your routine to a table valued function rather than a stored procedure and then you can say

```
select * from fn_runRoutine_Job()
```

Comment: `select * from fn_runRoutine_Job()`... stored functions only return scalars in MySQL.  There are no "table valued functions."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, Yes exactly, might be a miss from my side. Only way is to go with a temporary table.

Comment: Thanks, i realised only one column is needed e.g the calculated distance , so a function would suffice here.